# pure virtual declarations in subclasses

Tags: c++, abstract-class, pure-virtual, virtual-functions

i have a a couple c++ interfaces like this:

```
struct IThese {
virtual void doThesethings() = 0;
}

struct IThose : public IThese {
virtual void doThoseOtherThings() = 0;
}
```

Notice that IThose implement their own method, but also implements those from the other interface, so the idea is that implementors of `IThose` will *need to implement both*

**Question:** do i need to redeclare `doThesethings` in `IThose`?

if not, what would happen if i did it? would it shadow the `IThese` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently `class IThose` is abstract class** and you don't have to redeclare `doTheseThings()` inside it. You can **choose to** implement `doTheseThings()` inside `class IThose`.

If `doThesethings()` is implemented in `class IThose`, then it's child class (which derive `IThose`) **may or may not** implement it. But they **must implement** `doThoseOtherThings()`, if they don't want to be abstract.

**abstract class: contains at least one pure `virtual` method within it or via its base class

Comment: what you are saying is that with the current declaration of IThose, concrete classes deriving from it, will still need to implement both abstract methods, right?

Comment: @lurscher, If `IThose` is implementing `doTheseThings` inside its body, then concrete `class`es can either implement it or not. But if `IThose` doesn't implement `doTheseThings` then concrete classes must have to implement it. `doThoseOtherThings()` is mandatory to implement, because it's introduced by `class IThose` itself.

Answer (score 1):

You do **not** need to redeclare `doThesethings()` in `IThose`.

A class (or struct) that inherits from `IThese` **must** implement `doThesethings()`.

A class (or struct) that inhertis from `IThose` **must** implement both `doThesethings()` and 'doThoseOtherThings()`.

To answer your other question, if you were to redeclare `doThesethings()` in `IThose`, different compilers might react differently.  Either it won't have any effect because the compiler will consider it redundant, or it will be an error because a pure virtual method was declared twice and was pure virtual in both cases.

Comment: The last paragraph is wrong. It's not an error to override a pure virtual function with another pure virtual function, and it's only "redundant" if the override doesn't have a definition.